# The bipartite graph admits a perfect match

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G:=(X+Y,E)$ be an finite bipartite graph with $|X|=|Y|=n$. I want to show that if $|E| \geq n^2-n+1$ then $G$ admits a perfect matching. I was thinking to use the Hall Theorem to show it but I have trouble to start the proof. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hint: show that, iff Hall's condition is not satisfied, then $|E|\le n^2-n$.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint, please have a look at the edit...

Comment: Hall only requires $|N(S)|\ge|S|$ so failure of Hall's condition means that $|N(S)|\lt|S|$. Can you use that to show that $|S|(n-|N(S)|)\ge n$?

Comment: I am now futher in my calculation, see answer below but I don't see how this inequality gives me a failure or a satisfaction of the Hall condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should convince yourself that the given bound is sharp. That is, try to find an example with $|E| = n^2 - n$, but admit no perfect matching. You will see that almost every pair of vertices are joined by an edge in this case.

Now, let's start the main proof. If Hall's condition is not satisfied, then there should be a bad subset $A$ of $X$ such that $|A|>|N(A)|$. To find contradiction, we should expect the number of edges in this case to be smaller than $n^2-n+1$. The motivation is as follows:

> There are no edges between $A$ and $Y-N(A)$. So, if $|N(A)|$ is small,
> there are a lot of non-edges between $A$ and $Y$. This will force the
> total number of edges to be smaller than $n^2 - n + 1$.

Now, we just need to put our ideas in numbers. I hope this gives you a good head-start.

Hint: it is much cleaner if you focus on bounding non-edges rather than edges.

There is also a really cute proof of this result using probabilistic method. Check out https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/ProbabilisticMethod/ProbabilisticMethod.pdf#page53 if you are interested.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Well to find an example with $n^2-n$ that has no perfect match is not hard... $K_{n,n-1}$ should be an example. But now I could convince myself that there are no edges between $A$ and $Y-N(A)$ but I don't see how to proceed..

Comment: Total number of edges between $X$ and $Y$ is at most $n^2$. Since $|E|\ge n^2-(n-1)$, the number of "missing" edges (between $X$ and $Y$) is at most $n-1$. This gives us the inequality $|A|(n-|N(A)|) \le n-1$. This will force $|A|$ to take some particular values.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the inequality right... We have that there are no edges between $A$ & $Y-(N(A)$. Now we have that these two sets are disjoint and at most differs of $n-1$, so we can conclude this inequality, right? Good but how can I show that with that we have a perfect matching in $G$?

Comment: I guess the inequality $|A|(n-|N(A)| \leq n-1$ should give us $|A|\leq|N(A)|$ but I am not able to deduce this from the equation... Can you please help me once more out?

Comment: Since we assumed $|A| > |N(A)|$, the inequality implies $|A|(n-|A|)< n-1$. By some algebra, you can see that values of $|A|$ that satisfy the inequality are ridiculous, creating a contradiction.